# Proof a theorem on website "carnap"

Tags: logic

I'm doing this proofing question on a website called Carnap, I can't get the last line correct. Here is a screenshot of the question along with my answer, I cannot write it in the right format so I have to use this screenshot. I would really appreciate some help thanks
[image]

Comment: From line 7) under assumption $B$, you have to derive **directly** $B \lor (A \lor A)$. This is the way Didjunction Intro works.

Comment: I tried that as well doesn't work

Comment: What is the output of the prover: the left or the right image?

Comment: Try deleting line 8...